# iOS data source delegation

Tags: delegates, ios5, protocols, datasource, cs193p

I've been working through the Stanford CS193p course for iOS 5.0 development (available on iTunes U) and have run into a problem whilst attempting Assignment 3 ([pdf](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/assignments/Assignment%203_2.pdf)).

I am trying to implement a graphing calculator on top of a previous calculator model I have developed. In my storyboard I have added a "graph" button to my calculator which segues to a new view controller. Inside this is a view called 'GraphView'. I need to delegate the data source for this view. I can set it inside my GraphViewController like so:

```
self.graphView.dataSource = self;
```

I can also set that in Interface Builder. What I would like to do is set it to my CalculatorViewController, which first sent the segue message, but there is no mention of GraphViewController or GraphView in it's code, so I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Interface Builder would not let me drag the data source out of it's own view's frame either.

Short version: I want to delegate my data source from my Graph View to my CalculatorViewController. See the storyboard here: [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHzZ6.png).

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the prepareForSegue function.  You can find a similar example to how this is done in PsychologistViewController.m.